# Impedir que un elemento se elimine si es que existe en una tabla

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Tengo una tabla `productos` que tiene un `id_categoria` que esta relacionada con la tabla `categoria`. Mi pregunta es cómo tengo que hacer si quiero que al intentar eliminar una categoría, si esa categoría está relacionada con un producto, no dejar que se elimine. Si por lo contrario no tiene ningún producto relacionado eliminarse la categoría.

Migracion productos

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('creates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('descripcion',5000);
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->bigInteger('id_categoria')->unsigned()->unique();
        //$table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias')->onDelete('set null');
        $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Migracion Categorias

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->foreignId('id')
        ->references('id')->on('productos')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

pero como hago un if para para validar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la migracion puedes añadir los bloqueos necesarios en caso de que renombren la llave primaria y/o la quieran eliminar

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users');
      ->onUpdate('cascade')
      ->onDelete('restrict');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

--- Edicion ---

Ok, la validacion de datos no se hace en las vistas, se tiene que hacer en el controlador y de alli llamar la vista correcta, por ejemplo:

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\Product  $product
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Product $product)
{
    try {
        $product->delete();
        return view('product');
    } catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
        $error_code = $e->errorInfo[1];
        return view('product_error',['error' => $error_code]);
    }
}
```

Comment: pero en la migracion de productos o categoria

Comment: en la de categoria

Comment: Schema::create('creates', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('descripcion',5000);
            $table->string('foto');
            $table->bigInteger('id_categoria')->unsigned()->unique();
            //$table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
            $table->string('nombre');
            

            
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: esas son  mis migraciones

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código fuente allí para que sea más claro para todos...

Comment: listo ya esta editada

Comment: bro por favor ayuda se me esta complicando esto como hago la validacion en el blade