# Integridad Referencial con Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Hola buenas tardes primero que todo los pongo en contexto tengo 2 tablas una productos y otra categorias
estas estan relacionadas.

Migracion de productos

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('creates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('descripcion',5000);
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->bigInteger('id_categoria')->unsigned()->unique();
        //$table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias')->onDelete('set null');
        $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Esta es la migracion de categorias

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->foreignId('id')
        ->references('id')->on('productos')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Ok ahora lo que trato de hacer es que al dar click en eliminar categoria se consulte si hay un producto que tiene esa categoria que trato de borrar si no hay ningun producto se puede borrar pero si hay productos vinculados a esa categoria mandar un alert que no se puede borrar

categoria controller

```
  public function destroy($id)
{
    //



}
```

Comment: Hola, por favor lee [ask], para poderte ayudar debes proveer un [mcve] de lo que hayas intentado al momento así como dudas puntuales

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Impedir que un elemento se elimine si es que existe en una tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/447986/impedir-que-un-elemento-se-elimine-si-es-que-existe-en-una-tabla)

Comment: eso veo men pero que pongo aqui

Comment: (Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Comment: @Baruch no dupliques preguntas por favor, veo que son prácticamente lo mismo, sugiero elimines esta y te enfoques en la anterior, haciendo los comentarios y ediciones necesarios