# Validacion uno a muchos laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Si al intentar borrar una categoria esa categoria tiene un producto relacionado no se puede borrar pero si esa categoria no tiene productos relacionados se podra borrar

Funcion destroy de categorias

```
 public function destroy($id)
{   

    $categoria = categoria::find($id);
    $producto = create::where('id_categoria',$id)->get();
    //
   
   if($categoria == null || $producto != null){

    return back();
   }
    else{
        categoria::destroy($id);
     }
   
}
```

Migracion de la tabla categorias

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
    });
}
```

Migracion de productos

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('creates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->string('descripcion',5000);
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->bigInteger('id_categoria')->unsigned()->unique();
        //$table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias')->onDelete('set null');
        $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Ya te lo dijeron antes, "**No dupliques la pregunta**" https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/447986

Comment: Pero es que aún no logro resolver

Comment: Elimina esta y la primera pregunta que hiciste para conservar esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/447986 (Ya que tiene una respuesta) y poder ayudarte ahi, de hecho ya hice una repuesta

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Impedir que un elemento se elimine si es que existe en una tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/447986/impedir-que-un-elemento-se-elimine-si-es-que-existe-en-una-tabla)

Comment: @Baruch como te recomendaba dale atención a tu publicación original si aún tienes dudas que no logras resolver, hacer esto solo provocará que te cierren las preguntas, además es un tanto confuso que digas *aún no lo logro resolver* cuando veo que ya aceptaste una respuesta y eso al menos para mi es un indicio de que ya obtuviste una respuesta a tu problema